# How to plot vertical segments with overlapping x?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
f=read.table(pipe('curl -s https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZwiL.gif | tail -c +43 | zcat'), header=T)
f$x=asinh(f$x)
f$y1=asinh(f$y1)
f$y2=asinh(f$y2)
png('out.png')
with(f, plot(c(x, x), c(y1, y2), type='n'))
with(f, points(x, y1, pch=20))
with(f, segments(x, y1, x, y2))
dev.off()
```

I want to plot a segment plot using the above data. The current result is like this.

It is not very viewable. The column x is of integers, which are not spaced relatively evenly. I'd think one may do something like 1) grouping them into bins, 2) plot the bins in the asinh scale, 3) applying gitter in x in each bin to resolve the overlapping problem.

3 may be changed to 3' by sorting the segments based on y1, so that the y1 is ordered from low to high (from left to right) in each bin. However, this may introduce a lot more code.

How can I plot this data so that it is more viewable (at least as explained in the above two methods, e.g., gitter vs sort, but other more creative methods are also welcome) than the current solution without having to write too much code? (Both plain R and ggplot2 answers are welcome.)

[image]

Comment: The data is already there. You need to look at it closely.

Comment: minimal reproducible example through steganography, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me what quantities / comparisons you want to make "more viewable," since that phrase is somewhat subjective and contextual. A couple ideas that occur to me:

- Use a transformation for the scale so the data can be displayed in original units (if that's important to your situation), and add some alpha to make the areas of higher point density clearer, and use different colors to distinguish the points from the range above.

---

```
library(ggplot2)
asinh_trans <- scales::trans_new(name = "asinh",
                                 transform = base::asinh,
                                 inverse = base::sinh)

ggplot(f, aes(x, y1, xend = x, yend = y2)) +
  geom_segment(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = asinh_trans) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = asinh_trans)
```

[image]

- use a sample of points to give more "indicative" sense of what's typical:

---

```
ggplot(dplyr::slice_sample(f, n= 200), aes(x, y1, xend = x, yend = y2)) +
  geom_segment(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = asinh_trans) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = asinh_trans)
```

[image]

- Focus on the distribution of the x values, which have some banding at 21, 22, 30, etc.

---

```
ggplot(f, aes(x, y1, xend = x, yend = y2)) +
  # geom_segment(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, size = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = asinh_trans, breaks = 2^c(0:12)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = asinh_trans) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image]

---

EDIT -- additional approach which assigns each observation its own x value, so none of the data is overlapping, while preserving the x value within 1 on the scaled scale. It will take a very wide figure to see every point individually, but it should be possible.

```
asinh_trans <- scales::trans_new(name = "asinh",
                                 transform = base::asinh,
                                 inverse = base::sinh)
f %>%
  arrange(x, y1) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(x_adj = x + row_number()/n()) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x_adj, y1, xend = x_adj, yend = y2)) +
  geom_segment(alpha = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = asinh_trans, 
                     breaks = c(1*10^(0:5),
                                2*10^(0:5), 
                                5*10^(0:5))) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = asinh_trans)
```

[image]

Comment: Viewable as least should satisfy the requirement that the segments in general do not overlap each other, even they share the same x and the same y range. None of the solutions here satisfy those requirements.

Comment: Please put any requirements into your question, that was not obvious to me at all.

Comment: Ok, so for example you have 140 observations where x = 22, and 125 where x = 41. Do want each of those to be shown non-overlapping?

Comment: Yes. Using the sort method, it surely can be shown. The image can be very wide. But that is OK, as I can use a pdf viewer to zoom in to check.

Comment: What's your tradeoff between "show all the points" and "place them to scale on the x axis"? If you just sort them in order and use the row as the x value, you can fit your 2,276 observations on a wide axis.

Comment: But then the scale is completely missing. I still want to have info of x be preserved. In other word, just knowing the order of x in plot is not sufficient.

Comment: See edited answer. I hope that helps, I'll move on from this question now.